# How to add onclicklistener to dynamically generated text views

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I have dynamically created Textviews in my application. I want to give On click event to this textviews.. When I click on the textview, I need to get the id of the textview..

Comment: please put some snippet of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You try following code.

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);

    text.setText("text here");
    ll.addView(text);
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID : "+arg0.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

in that "ll" is Layout which add textview and after adding put clickListener() for click event.

hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`setOnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) and [`getId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
// Set up your text view
textView.setId(1); // Any number is ok
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId(); // This is the id you want
        // Do whatever you want here
    }
});
```

Comment: Any number is not OK. What if you manage somehow to give the same ID to an already added view?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating `TextView`s dynamically than just implement `OnClickListener`:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int vId = v.getId();

    }

}
```

and set it to dynamically created view like this:

```
private TextView createTextView(int vId) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setId(vId);
    textView.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    return textView;    
}
```

P.S.: Don't forget to create & initilialize `myClickListener` in your `Activity`.