# How to add onclicklistener to dynamically generated textViews?

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, onclicklistener

I write code to generate dynamic TextViews as a user  what he looked like and any time

, But the problem  each text view has only one click, 
And any other click on textView does not reach onClick
I found some answers but not work with my code... Please help me.
 This is my code

```java
    RelativeLayout mainBackground = findViewById(R.id.mainBackground);

    private void AddTextView() {
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new 
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setId(textCount);
      tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
      tv.setText(text);
      tv.setTextColor(colorChooser);
      tv.setTextSize(size);

      tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("textID",view.getId()+"");  
            }
        });

      this.mainBackground.addView(tv);
    }
```

Comment: you have id for your textview. You can use that to setOnClicListener

Comment: `But the problem each text view has only one click, And any other click on textView does not reach onClick` you can only have one clickListener per textView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add onclicklistener to dynamically generated text views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783483/how-to-add-onclicklistener-to-dynamically-generated-text-views)

Comment: You are adding the textviews dynamically on relativelayout and not specifying the textviews exact position during creation. Because of this all your dynamically created textviews are overlapping on top of each other and probably causing conflicts and unwanted behavior with the onClick. Suggestion would be to change relative layout to linear layout.

Comment: @Azhar92 thank you for helping me, I tried linear layout and the same behavior 
"one-click for each view"

Comment: Can you post the output of the Log which you are printing from multiple textviews